# Atomic Broadcast Exercice

Tags: parallel-processing, monitor, concurrent-programming

I'm trying to solve the exercice 5.10 of the book
"Foundations of Multithreaded, Parallel, and Distributed Programming".

The exercice is

"Assume one producer process and N consumer processes share a bounded buffer having B slots. The producer deposits messages in the buffer; consumers fetch them. Every message deposited by the producer is to be received by all N consumers. Futthermore, each consumer is to receive the messages in the order theu were deposited. However, consumers can receive messages at different times. For example, one consumer could receive up to B more messages than another if the second consumer is slow.
Develop a monitor that implements this kind of communication. Use Signal and Continue discipline."

Can someone help me, please?

Thank you very much!

--
EDIT:

I'm commenting now what I already made (cause I thought that the question was very big if I wrote everything that).

```
/* creating a buffer of B positions. */
global buffer[B];  
Monitor {

cond ok_write;
cond ok_read;
int stamp_buffer[B] = [0, 0, .., 0]

request_write (int pos){
    if (stamp_buffer[pos] > 0)
        wait(ok_write);
    write_message (buufer[pos]);
    stamp_buffer[pos] = N;
    signalAll (ok_read);
}

request_read (int pos){
    if (stamp_buffer[pos] == 0)
        wait (ok_read);
    stamp_buffer[pos] --;
}

release_read (int pos){
    if (stamp_buffer[pos]==0)
        signal(ok_write);
}

}
```

---

So, I think that I still have that problem: "A reader can read the same message two times."

The basic idea of my algorithm is:
The writer write in a position "pos" and set the value of stamp[pos] to N.
Then, when each reader read the position pos, it do stamp[pos] - 1.
So, if stamp[pos] is zero, the message buffer[pos] was already readed N times and the writer can write in this position again.

But, if some reader read a message two times (or more), the writer can wirte a new message in the position pos and some reader will not read the old message.

Comment: Thank you.
I'm commenting now what I already did (cause I thought that the question was very big if I wrote everything that).

/* creating a buffer of B positions. */
global buffer[B];  

Monitor {

cond ok_write;
cond ok_read;
int stamp_buffer[B] = [0, 0, .., 0]

request_write (int pos){
..if (stamp_buffer[pos] > 0)
....wait(ok_write);
..write_message (buufer[pos]);
..stamp_buffer[pos] = N;
..signalAll (ok_read);
}

request_read (int pos){
..if (stamp_buffer[pos] == 0)
....wait (ok_read);
..stamp_buffer[pos] --;
}

release_read (int pos){
..if (stamp_buffer[pos]==0){
....signal(ok_write);
}
}

Comment: I'm sorry.
I'm new here and I did nor know that we could not to post code in the comments.

Comment: Ok, Yve.
I'm reading the links now.

Cannot you to cancel the negavite votes?
Thank you.